# How to change the relationship label with the direction?

Tags: enterprise-architect

I've created a custom toolbox with given relationships between the stereotypes.

[image: These are some of the custom relationships]

[image: These are the stereotypes and how the relationships can occur]

I am expecting that, with the '_MeaningBackwards' and '_MeaningForward' attributes setup, the connection label would change pending on the direction. However, when I use the toolbox this does not happen.

[image]

I was expecting this:

[image]

Is there any way of making this happen or do I need to create a different relationship in the toolbox for each direction?

Comment: What is a _connection label_?

Comment: The text over the arrow in the diagram

Comment: That would be the role name, wouldn't it?

Comment: Unless you clarify what you actually want to achieve it will be hard to give you any meaningful help.

Comment: I would expect that the connections in the diagram present the text from the MeaningForward and MeaningBackwards attributes. I'm not sure how to explain better...

Comment: Well, Geert explained it perfectly. They are meant to show the text in the context menu. You should not explain your confusion, but what you are trying to achive. Make a picture (with Paint or what) and ask how to get this being done with EA. Use the right terminology. So what is the text you want to show where under which condition?

Comment: I added a figure showing what I was expecting to get

Comment: That's simply another stereotype. I don't see why you would want two stereotypes that mean the same thing but in the other direction. Best to stick with the «Requires» stereotype as that follows the UML dependency direction and meaning. «Required by» would only create confusing (see ArchiMate «used by» relation that is now renamed to «serving», but still goes in the wrong direction. I have to explain that one each time I use it)

Answer (score 2):

The label you are referring to is the stereotype.

If you want different thing to show up at that label, you'll need to make different stereotypes for `«Requires»` and `«Required By»`.

I just don't know why you would want two stereotypes that mean the same thing in the opposite direction. My advice is to keep only `«Requires»`.

So if you have a relation `A -«Requires»-> B` that means both

- `A` requires `B`
- `B` is required by `A`

There's no need for two separate relations with different stereotypes.

If you want to know how to use the `_MeaningBackwards` and `_MeaningForwards` attributes correctly see this question: [How do I use the _MeaningForwards and _MeaningBackwards when defining stereotypes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66566857/how-do-i-use-the-meaningforwards-and-meaningbackwards-when-defining-stereotype)

Comment: I changed it in the metaclass but i still don't get the labels right... can you show me a diagram with the connection you exemplified e both ways?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by labels, but I've added an image of the result in the quicklinker.

Comment: Answering on unclear questions is a bit touchy always...

Comment: I mean the connection's labels that are visible in the diagram. In my question's last figure both are labeled "Requires"

Comment: That's not what you said above. These are the stereotypes.

Comment: @GeertBellekens Leave the answer as it is (as addition) and prepend the right answer to create two stereotypes (or an additional to «requires»).

Comment: @qwerty_so yeah, or I could create a new question on how to use the meaningforwards and meaningbackwards and then self-answer it with this answer.

Comment: lol, yes. You would then need to close it as duplicate xD

Comment: @qwerty_so it's no a duplicate, but a different question. I created the other self-answered question to not loose the answer I already wrote.