# How do I use the _MeaningForwards and _MeaningBackwards when defining stereotypes?

Tags: enterprise-architect

When defining stereotypes in a UML profile in EA there are special attributes `_MeaningForwards` and `_MeaningBackwards`.

How do I use those exactly to define the entries in the quicklinker?
When I add them to the stereotype, they don't show up in the quicklinker.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attributes `_MeaningForwards` and `_MeaningBackwards` should be added to the **metaclass**, not to the **stereotype**.

[image]

If you use the profile helper to create them for you, you can't miss.

[image]

This is also the reason why you should not reuse metaclasses, but instead create a metaclass for each stereotype.

The result can be seen in the quicklinker

[image]

Comment: That's what I expected :-)